# Laravel 5.7 where + diff

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

> Problem is i want to use diff because in my show.blade.php i already i have that `id=1` item. Then how to skip that item and take.

```
 public function show($id){
 $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
 $collection = Product::where('request_register',$product->request_register)->diff('request_register',$product->request_register)->get();
    return view('products.show', compact('product','collection'));
}
```

Error is:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::diff()

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `diff()` method is defined in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`, you need to call the method `get()` before calling the `diff()` method.

```
public function show($id){
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
    $collection = Product::where('request_register', $product->request_register)
        // Call get() to return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection.
        ->get()
        ->diff('request_register',$product->request_register);
    return view('products.show', compact('product','collection'));
}
```

See:

[Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder | Laravel API](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_get)

[Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection | Laravel API](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_diff)